# call void in IBAction

Tags: ios, button, text, label

I have the following:

```
-(void)turnBlue:(DetailVC *) controller {
self.Label.text = controller.selected.name;
self.selected = controller.selected;
[controller.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

I'm trying to enter from my ibaction here:

```
- (IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender {
//filler code here
}
```

I'm trying

```
[self turnBlue:selected];
```

But am getting 'incompatible pointer types sending...'

I've tried controller, what details am I missing?

Comment: `selected` should be object of `DetailVC`.

Comment: The exact and complete error message would be helpful.

Comment: your turn blue method expecting DetailVC object as a parameter, and you r passing selected thats why u r getting error. see @"NeverHopeless" answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
// Allocate or get already created instance of `DetailVC`
DetailVC *controller = [[DetailVC alloc] initWithNibName..........];

// Pass instance to `turnBlue` function:
[self turnBlue:controller];
```

`turnBlue` can only accept a parameter of type `DetailVC`, while you are passing `selected` which seems not to be of type `DetailVC` so you are receiving incompetible pointer type error.

Hope it helps!